# How to iterate multiple URLs in Scrapy and save them after each iteration

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to crawl all historical coin data from https://coinmarketcap.com. So, I am trying to scrape data using scrapy. I am able to scrape all data from the website but I am unable to save them all. It only saves about 2000 entries whereas actually, it might be above 20000.Also, I think the code that I've written can be optimized but I am unable to do so.

The folder format is :

- hist.py
- utils.py
- coins.csv

This is the utils.py file code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import re

today = str(date.today()).replace("-","")

def sub(s):
    s = re.sub(r"\s+", '-', s)
    return s

def url(s):
    s = 'coinmarketcap.com/currencies/'+s+'/historical-data/?start=20130428&end='+today
    return s

def append(s):
    s = 'https://'+s
    return s

def load():
    data = pd.read_csv('coins.csv')
    data.drop('Unnamed: 0', inplace = True, axis = 1)
    data['Coin'] = data['Coin'].apply(lambda x : sub(x))
    data['URL'] = data['Coin'].apply(lambda x : url(x))
    data['start'] = data['URL'].apply(lambda x : append(x))
    return data
```

This is the hist.py file code:

```
import scrapy
import pandas as pd
import utils

data = utils.load()

class CoinSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'coinspider'
    allowed_domains = data['URL']
    start_urls = data['start']

    def parse(self, response):
        scraped_info = {
            'title' : response.css('.table tr ::text').extract()
            }

        title = response.css('.table tr ::text').extract()

        data = pd.DataFrame({'Data' : title})
        data.to_csv('historical.csv', sep = ',')
        yield scraped_info
```

Run the scrapy file above using:

```
scrapy runspider hist.py
```

And here is the csv file link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13UR5TWGEfz124R9yRaYvafbfxGvCZ6vZ/view?usp=sharing

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please read the question properly @Parfait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might lie in the fact that you're overwriting the output .csv file for each crawled URL.

Try to substitute

```
data.to_csv('historical.csv', sep = ',')
```

with

```
with open('historical.csv', 'a') as f:
    data.to_csv(f, sep = ',', header=False)
```

EDIT:

```
curr = response.url.split('/')[4] # get name of current currency
with open('historical'+curr+'.csv', 'a') as f:
    data.to_csv(f, sep = ',', header=False)
```

This appends data to the file.

Comment: This seems to solve the problem of saving the data. A csv file of size 116MB got generated. This one csv has all currencies, but I need to save every currency in a different csv. Can you also suggest how do I save every scraped URL into a different csv file?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EA-DuWEFbzM89x13681cNxB2vLU4jRYi/view?usp=sharing This is the link to the new csv. You can remove the '\n' by using pd.replace('\n', np.nan) and then pd.dropna(inplace = True). Now as you can see there is a column named '0'. The value '1' in the '0'column is repeated. So I want to split the dataframe into smaller dataframes. Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: @DhavalThakkar One way to do it: in the `parse` function extract the name of the currency from `response.url` and add it to the file name. Best is to write an [item pipeline](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) and put the `data_to_csv` function in there telling the scraper where to save each item.

Comment: This really helps. Thanks for the answer @user2314737.